# Browser Compatibility Problem On Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g

I am using Oracle 10g DB with 10 users(in IE 7 browser).I can not use my application in windows 10.Please guide me for this problem

I am using Oracle 10g DB for my company transaction.That is one physical server with 10 users.This is licensed version.This application only works in IE 7 and below versions.Now i changed all user system to Windows 10. But i cannot run my oracle 10g Application in IE 10 and other browers. Please help me for this issue

Comment: "i cannot run my oracle 10g Application in IE 10 and other browsers" - what does that mean? What happens when you try it?

Comment: My oracle application web based application.It works only on internet explorer 7.But i cannot run my oracle application in higher version of IE

Comment: What front end are you using?

Comment: That is oracle 10g forms. Sir